# Intercepting a REST call with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

For a particular REST server that I'm working against the `DELETE` method has two varieties. When called without a query parameter the delete action results in an update taking place where the underlying resource's workflow status is "marked for deletion". If, however, an immediate deletion *is* the goal than you simply add the query parameter `?immediate=true`.

I'd to programmatically send choose which of these varieties to send based on some simple client side logic but I'm not sure how I would get my query parameter added to the `DELETE` request.

In both cases, I'm assuming that calling DS.Model's `.destroyRecord()` or `.deleteRecord()` is appropriate. I'm also wondering if this is a case where I would need to create a custom DS.Adapter. I'd love to avoid that but if I must do it are there any good examples of this? Is there a way to inherit the implementation of all adapter methods and only override what needs changing (the documentation indicated that DS.Adapter is purely abstract)?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to to override the RESTAdapter:

```
App.ProductAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

   deleteRecord: function(store, type, record) {
     //do ajax stuff here

     //return a promise that resolves or rejects based on ajax outcomes
     return new Em.RSVP.Promise( function(resolve, reject){ resolve(); } );
   },

})
```

The following is not required but I use it to wrap my ajax request in a promise:

```
function ajaxPromise (url, type, hash) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        hash = hash || {};
        hash.url = url;
        hash.type = type;
        hash.dataType = 'json';
        hash.success = function(json) {
            Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
        };
        hash.error = function(json) {
           if (json && json.then) { json.then = null }
           Ember.run(null, reject, json);
        };
    $.ajax(hash);
    });
}
```

You can then pass it type DELETE with any additional parameters in the hash or add them to the URL.  e.g.

```
deleteRecord: function(store, type, record) {
   var promise = new ajaxPromise(URL, "DELETE", hash);
   promise.then(function(result){
     //do stuff here with result
   });
   return promise
}
```

Comment: thanks, this looks promising; will play around with it tomorrow. in the mean time, do you know what the best way of auto-generating the endpoint URL? I'm sure i can code a solution to this but I'd ideally like it to be more DRY and just reuse ember-data's code.

Comment: You can try this.buildURL(type.typeKey) where this is the RESTAdapter

Comment: How about picking up other customisations in the adapter like API namespace, etc.?

Comment: Ken you can try this.store.adapterFor('client').buildURL('signin')